# Separate mouse clicks for circles and background in D3 circle pack

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, circle-pack

How do I get two separate click events from my code below

1."Circle Click" will be displayed when I click in a circle.

2.Then immediately after the "Back ground clicked" alert is displayed.

What I require is to have both events independent of each other, so the "Circle Click" will alert when I click in a circle
and "Back ground clicked" will ONLY alert when I click on the background i.e. the chart container.

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var json = {
                    "name": "flare",
                    "children": [
                        { "name": "<div>test1<br>test again</div>", "size": 20, "color": "#ff0000" , "id": 1},
                        { "name": "test2", "size": 40, "color": "#ffff00", "id": 2},
                        { "name": "test3", "size": 60, "color": "#ff0000", "id": 3},
                        { "name": "test4", "size": 80, "color": "#ff00ff", "id": 4 },
                        { "name": "test5", "size": 100, "color": "#0000ff", "id": 5}
                    ]
                };

                var r = 400,
                    format = d3.format(",d"),
                    fill = d3.scale.category20c();

                var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
                    .sort(null)
                    .size([r, r])

                    .padding(1.5);

                var vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
                    .attr("width", r)
                    .attr("height", r)
                    .attr("class", "bubble")
                    .on("click", function (d) { alert("Back ground clicked"); });

                var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
                    .data(bubble.nodes(classes(json))
                    .filter(function (d) { return !d.children; }))
                    .enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "node")
                    .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });


                node.append("circle")
                     .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r; })
                     .style("fill", function (d) { return d.color; })
                     .on("click", function (d) { alert("Circle Clicked"); });

                node.append("text")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .attr("dy", "0.3em")
                    .text(function (d) { return d.dispText.substring(0, d.r / 3); });



                function classes(root) {
                    var classes = [];

                    function recurse(name, node) {
                        if (node.children)
                            node.children.forEach(function (child) {
                                 recurse(node.name, child);
                            });
                        else
                            classes.push({
                                packageName: name, dispText: node.name, value: node.size, color: node.color, id: node.id});
                    }

                    recurse(null, root);
                    return { children: classes };
                }

            });

        </script>
```

Comment: Maybe you could post the rendered html?

Comment: Im thinking event.stopPropagation() will help here: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 1):

Remove the onclick event from the vis object and add it to a background rectangle:

```
var background  = vis.append("rect")
                  .attr("width", r)
                  .attr("height", r)
                  .on("click", function (d) { alert("Background clicked"); });
```

Make sure that you add the background rectangle before the circles so that they appear in front of it.

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HKE2j/

Answer (score 0):

I think its that:

```
 node.append("circle")
     .attr("r", function (d) {
     return d.r;
 })
     .style("fill", function (d) {
     return d.color;
 })
     .on("click", function (d) {
     d.stopPropagation();
     alert("Circle Clicked");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Im thinking event.stopPropagation() will help here: api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation